# DevExpress grid, selecting row on checkbox only in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, devexpress

I have a problem in selecting rows using devexpress. I got a row that should get marked only on checkbox (now its getting check on row click). I had to add onRowClick because I have to open details, and interaction is weird. I open the popup with details but that row becomes checked.

Normal devex behavior is to check row on click, is there a way to disable it and enable it only on checkbox? I know it works, cant find how :/

Code:

```
    <dx-data-grid
      id="gridContainer" (onRowClick)="showDetails($event)">
    </dx-data-grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from your question is, you don't want to check/select the **check-box** after click on a record. You only want to check/select the record after check on the particular check-box of a record.

If I'm not wrong, there is a **[showCheckBoxesMode]** property for *dx-data-grid* where you can pass **always** value to select a record `only after user check the check-box, not click on the record.`

For example,

In component.html

```
 <dx-data-grid
   id="gridContainer" (onRowClick)="showDetails($event)">

  <dxo-selection
     [showCheckBoxesMode]="checkBoxesMode"
     mode="multiple">
  </dxo-selection>

 </dx-data-grid>
```

In component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent {
 //Your rest declarations goes here

 checkBoxesMode: string;
 constructor(service: Service) {
     //Your rest code goes here
     this.checkBoxesMode = 'always'
  }
 }
```

To know more about selection modes, please [follow this.](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MultipleRecordSelectionModes/Angular/Light/)

Hope it helps :)